# pytorch: RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. with enough GPU memory

Tags: pytorch

Torch Error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 392.00 MiB (GPU 0; 10.73 GiB total capacity; 9.47 GiB already allocated; 347.56 MiB free; 9.51 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

I checked GPU resource by nvidia-smi, showing no other running process and memory-usage: 10/10989MiB.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.56       Driver Version: 418.56       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  On   | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   30C    P8    10W / 230W |     10MiB / 10989MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried following 3 methods:

1. with torch.no_grad();
2. torch.cuda.empty_cache();
3. reduce batch_size;

All of them did not work.

Comment: Clearly, your code is taking up more memory than is available. Using `watch nvidia-smi` in another terminal window, as suggested in an answer below, can confirm this. As to what consumes the memory -- you need to look at the code. If reducing the batch size to very small values does not help, it is likely a memory leak, and you need to show the code if you want more specific help.

Comment: I add code in : https://github.com/ojipadeson/e3d_lstm, a recurrence project. I haven't encountered such memory leak problem. Thank a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've checked the GPU allocation post the error "CUDA out of memory". and torch.no_grad() does'nt have anything to do with cuda memory. It depends on the problem you are defining and solving.

Try monitoring the cuda memory using `watch -n1 nvidia-smi`and if you can post the code of dataloader and your training loop. so, the we can assist you. But in general reducing the batch size and detaching the unnecessary tensors should improve this.